# WickedPDF and Wkhtmltopdf hangs in Rails depending on text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

For some reason, Rails seems to hang with WickedPDF. If I copy the HTML files from the /tmp/ directory and run the exact same commands as Rails, then it works just fine. I'm not understanding why, but sometimes when I adjust my text, it works and sometimes it doesn't. I haven't been able to pinpoint anything specifically.

Here's what the bottom of the output looks like in the Rails console when it does hang:

```
  Rendered [obfuscated].html.erb (39815.3ms)
  Rendered [obfuscated].html.erb (41037.4ms)
  Rendering layouts/report_header.html.erb
  Rendered layouts/report_header.html.erb (12.0ms)
  Rendering layouts/report_footer.html.erb
  Rendered layouts/report_footer.html.erb (0.4ms)
[wicked_pdf]: ["/root/myapp/bin/wicked_pdf", "--page-size", "Letter", "--margin-top", "25", "--margin-bottom", "17", "--margin-left", "10", "--margin-right", "10", "--header-html", "file:////tmp/wicked_header_pdf20191205-6854-1k3i748.html", "--footer-html", "file:////tmp/wicked_footer_pdf20191205-6854-cc6ntg.html", "file:////tmp/wicked_pdf20191205-6854-19958ts.html", "/tmp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20191205-6854-133sa6i.pdf"]
^CCompleted 500 Internal Server Error in 295092ms (ActiveRecord: 6927.8ms)



RuntimeError (Failed to execute:
["/root/myapp/bin/wicked_pdf", "--page-size", "Letter", "--margin-top", "25", "--margin-bottom", "17", "--margin-left", "10", "--margin-right", "10", "--header-html", "file:////tmp/wicked_header_pdf20191205-6854-1k3i748.html", "--footer-html", "file:////tmp/wicked_footer_pdf20191205-6854-cc6ntg.html", "file:////tmp/wicked_pdf20191205-6854-19958ts.html", "/tmp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20191205-6854-133sa6i.pdf"]
Error: PDF could not be generated!
 Command Error: ):

app/controllers/[obfuscated]/reports_controller.rb:96:in `block (2 levels) in generate_pdf'
app/controllers/[obfuscated]reports_controller.rb:48:in `generate_pdf'
- Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
=== puma shutdown: 12/05/2019 10:13 ===
- Goodbye!
Exiting
```

Here are the contents of `/root/myapp/bin/wickedpdf`:

```
#!/bin/bash
xvfb-run -- /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf "$0"
```

As you can see above, I had to ctrl c out of it because it wouldn't work. It just hung there for minutes. Am I doing something wrong or am I facing some kind of weird limitations with Rails?

***EDIT***

I've confirmed that by commenting out the `exe_path` in the `config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb` file, things generate just fine. I'm not quite sure why commenting out the initializer makes it work. I found this in another thread.

This definitely can't be a permanent solution, since my purpose behind using the initializer and `xvfb-run` is to generate javascript charts within the PDF.

***EDIT***

Here's the initializer:

```
# WickedPDF Global Configuration
#
# Use this to set up shared configuration options for your entire application.
# Any of the configuration options shown here can also be applied to single
# models by passing arguments to the `render :pdf` call.
#
# To learn more, check out the README:
#
# https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/blob/master/README.md

WickedPdf.config = {
  # Path to the wkhtmltopdf executable: This usually isn't needed if using
  # one of the wkhtmltopdf-binary family of gems.
  # exe_path: '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf',
  #   or
  # exe_path: Gem.bin_path('wkhtmltopdf-binary', 'wkhtmltopdf')
  exe_path: Rails.root.join("bin","wicked_pdf").to_s

  # Layout file to be used for all PDFs
  # (but can be overridden in `render :pdf` calls)
  # layout: 'pdf.html',
}
```

Comment: What's in the initializer?

Comment: Updated question to reflect the initializer contents.

Comment: The `bin/wicked_pdf` seems to be running `/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf`, but that may not necessarily be where the binary is located. Does `/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf https://google.com google.pdf` work?

Comment: It does work, but it's just not consistent, unfortunately.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? What do you mean by "not consistent"?

Comment:  Meaning if I added some random text that includes just basic HTML, then it may or may not work. Haven't been able to narrow down why or what particular HTML code or symbol that would cause this. Seems to work just fine when doing it manually